# Dump file outside the lxc container

Tags: linux, logging, containers, lxc, lxd

I am able to view syslog of my lxc container, from outside the container... by;

```
sudo lxc exec my-abc-container -- /root/tail  /usr/local/var/syslog
```

or either by tailing it

```
sudo lxc exec my-abc-container -- /root/tail --follow=name /usr/local/var/syslog
```

But I have no clue on how to dump this log in a file. Tired of finding similar question but nothing helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using file pull

```
lxc file pull my-abc-container/usr/local/var/syslog ./my-abc-container-syslog
```

Or by exec

```
lxc exec my-abc-container -- /bin/sh -c "cat /usr/local/var/syslog" > ./my-abc-container-syslog
```